# When using RMI in Java, do I have to create a Remote Interface?

Tags: java, rmi

Can I have an object simply extend `UnicastRemoteObject` and implement `Remote` and have all of its methods throw `RemoteException`?

e.g. 
`public class MyClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Remote`
vs.

`public class MyClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemoteInterface`
where `MyRemoteInterface` extends `Remote`

What's the difference between what I am suggesting and first "Designing a Remote Interface" as found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/designing.html?

Edit: Found "Essentially, the interface defines the client's view of the remote object." here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/server.html

If anyone could elaborate further that would be helpful, but that statement helps in understanding its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you described, but it doesn't accomplish anything. There is no remote interface, therefore there are no remote methods to call, so you can't do anything useful with the remote object or its stub.

Comment: If you can elaborate on why the remote object wouldn't be useful without the remote interface even though the object is also remote, that would be helpful.

Comment: I just did. There are no remote methods. What use is that?

Comment: Why can't a remote object have remote methods?

Comment: Became remote methods are defined in a remote interface, and there isn't one. You're going round in circles.